# Error in Decoding JSON with Python, exporting jqGrid

Tags: python, django, jqgrid, json

I am trying to export a jqGrid to CSV.  So far I added a button in the caption of the jqGrid that runs a javascript function directing to a CSV dowload url with a get request that has variables: 1) the url the JSON is located at and 2) the urlencoded headers from the jqGrid.

That I did like this ('grid' is the name of the grid to be downloaded):

```
function downloadGrid(grid) {  
    var columnNames = $(grid).getGridParam("colNames");
    columnNames = encodeURIComponent(columnNames)
    var dataLoc = $(grid).getGridParam("url");
    window.open( "/csv/download/?header=" + columnNames+"&jqgrid=" + dataLoc);
    }
```

In the view for writing the CSV file, I am attempting to read in some json using simplejson, but I am getting the error:

```
JSONDecodeError at /csv/download/

No JSON object could be decoded: line 1 column 0 (char 0)
```

I am using python 2.7.1 and simplejson 2.6.2, the traceback to simplejson goes to line 426.

The view looks like this:

```
import simplejson as json
import csv
import urllib2
from django.http import HttpResponse
from settings import PRIMARY_DOMAIN

def csv_writer(request):
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='text/csv')
    dat = '%s' % datetime.now()
    dat = dat[0:16]
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="CSV_%s.csv"' % dat

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    json_data = urllib2.urlopen(PRIMARY_DOMAIN + '/json/test_day/4982/')

    if request.method == "GET":
        if 'header' in request.GET.keys():
            header = request.GET['header'].split(',')
            writer.writerow([str(x) for x in header])
        if 'jqgrid' in request.GET.keys():
            url = request.GET['jqgrid']
            json_data = urllib2.urlopen(PRIMARY_DOMAIN + url)

    data = json.loads(json_data.read())

    ###below here may not work, haven't gotten past the json.loads()
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(row)

    return response
```

Here are two examples of json that has failed for me:

```
{"records": "0", "total": "1", "rows": [], "page": "1"}
```

and another is:

```
{"records": "17", "total": "1", "rows": [{"cell": ["04/05/10", 4, 196, 73, 3.0, 3.6, 1.5, 0.83, 8.0, 67, 28452, "", 115, 3.2, "$20.76", "$15.16"], "id": 1}, {"cell": ["01/30/10", 4, 131, 75, 4.0, 3.0, null, 1.33, null, 81, null, "", 141, 3.5, "$18.34", "$13.75"], "id": 2}, {"cell": ["01/06/10", 4, 107, 114, 3.3, 3.0, null, 1.1, null, 110, null, "", 283, 4.5, "$17.11", "$19.50"], "id": 3}, {"cell": ["11/28/09", 4, 68, 105, 3.7, 2.8, null, 1.32, null, 108, null, "", 214, 4.1, "$17.30", "$18.16"], "id": 4}, {"cell": ["11/02/09", 4, 42, 99, 4.1, 2.5, null, 1.64, null, 108, null, "", 47, 1.9, "$17.40", "$17.23"], "id": 5}, {"cell": ["10/02/09", 4, 11, 94, 3.9, 3.2, null, 1.22, null, 100, null, "", 17, 0.4, "$19.29", "$18.13"], "id": 6}], "page": "1"}
```

Comment: How certain are you that the script is seeing the JSON?

Comment: If you are using python 2.7 why not use json? http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: If you are using Django then why not use `django.utils.simplejson`?

Comment: We had some problems with a type (Decimal?) a year ago, so we updated to the more recent simplejson at the time, and that fixed it.  With django 1.4, maybe they have the more recent simplejson and wouldn't have the problem.  In any case we are encoding in the same view.py file and using the same simplejson for encoding and decoding.

Comment: Not entirely certain it is seeing the JSON, using a set_trace at the: json_data = urllib2.urlopen(PRIMARY_DOMAIN + '/json/test_day/4982/') I get an object <addinfourl at 61662472L whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x0.....>>

Comment: Changed the import to: from django.utils import simplejson as json.  Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a better way to go about it.  No need to open a new connection with urllib2, everything you need is within django.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
view_match = resolve('/json/test_day/4982/')
json_data = view_match.func(request,**view_match.kwargs).content
```